Why isn't mixfit from mixR function working inside the Shiny UI?
I am trying to use Shiny to make a UI that accepts a user uploaded excel file and performs analysis on it. I ran into a problem using the mixfit function from the mixR package.
I tried to isolate the mixfit function in a separate app so I know what is happening:
# Define the server logic for the Shiny application
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$testMixfit, {
    # Generate some test data with a fixed seed for reproducibility
    set.seed(123)
    test_data <- rnorm(100)
    
    # Debug print to ensure test_data exists
    print("Generated test data:")
    print(test_data)
    
    tryCatch({
      mixfit_result <- mixfit(test_data, ncomp = 2)
      
      # Debug print the mixfit result
      print("Mixfit result:")
      print(mixfit_result)

but the error that it puts out is:
[1] "Error in mixfit call:"
<simpleError in eval(mc, environment()): object 'test_data' not found>
I've also tried using reactive values, creating the random data inside the function, and other methods but I still run into this issue. I also ran the mixfit function in a separate notebook and it works just fine.
Here is the UI part of the code:
# Load the necessary libraries
library(shiny)
library(mixR)

# Define the user interface (UI) for the Shiny application
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test Mixfit Function"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("testMixfit", "Test Mixfit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("mixfitOutput")
    )
  )
)

and the output is just the plot:
output$mixfitOutput <- renderPrint({
        plot(mixfit_result, title="mixfit test")
})


test_data has to be defined outside the observeEvent or you need to use global assignments (<<-).

Does this answer your question? R Shiny Object not found - Evaluating a strings as code

I appreciate the suggestion, but when I tried these two methods the same error still occurs.

test_data outside observe event
`server <- function(input, output) {

Generate some test data with a fixed seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
test_data <- rnorm(100)
observeEvent(input$testMixfit, {
...`


test_data using a global assignment
`server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$testMixfit, {
# Generate some test data with a fixed seed for reproducibility

set.seed(123)

test_data <<- rnorm(100)`


Can you provide a full minimal example which still is not working for you?
